# Getting Sound BlasterX G6 Mic To Work Under Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: alsa, microphone, sound-blaster

I own a USB powered Sound BlasterX G6.  Audio output works with no problems at all under the latest LTS. However, I cannot get the mic input to work. I have tried various things after searching for answers to this, but I have had no success. I have a Logitech BRIO webcam connected, and Ubuntu is using its mic for input by default. The Logitech webcam mic does work, but I cannot show my Sound Blaster G6's mic to show in settings or function using alsamixer. Here is how Settings appear for me currently:
[image]

When I choose Microphone - Logitech BRIO, I do hear input. I get a lot of noise using the webcam's mic, because it is right next to my workstation. I have a headset plugged into my Sound Blaster G6, but I cannot get the external mic to work. When I use alsamixer to select Sound Blaster G6 and External mic, I lose all audio from the Sound Blaster completely. I can only recover audio by restarting alsa and/or rebooting.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?  The Logitech BRIO mic is the only functional mic in my system.  Perhaps there is an issue with systems having more than one mic?

Answer (score 1):

I now have my Sound BlasterX G6 mic input working with my headset. I followed the steps here: [Soundblaster G6 Microphone input doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123065/soundblaster-g6-microphone-input-doesnt-work). Note that I did try this previously, but it was not working for me. Now it is working successfully. After you execute the setmic script, note that the input device must be "Line In- Sound BlasterX G6". Even though this shows as the input, the actual input will be the external mic jack. This is tricky, but I got this working. I am not sure if later updates helped improve this, but it is working for me as of today.