# Options For Automatic Script Execution For Device Configuration

Tags: usb, sound, scripts, configuration

I finally have my Sound BlasterX G6 USB audio device working with both audio out and mic input under Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1.  To get it to work, I must manually execute a script each time I login. I followed the script suggestion here: [Soundblaster G6 Microphone input doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123065/soundblaster-g6-microphone-input-doesnt-work). I created the script listed under point #7. This now works when I manually execute this script after login. Just as this post stated, it fails when I attempt to automatically execute the script either using Startup Application to launch it, adding to /etc/rc.local, or any other attempts I have tried.

It would be nice to have this done automatically though.  Does anyone have any suggestions to have this script executed automatically at startup after a device readiness delay?