# MadDog GM302 not working well on ubuntu 22.04 and external sounblaster x5

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, streaming

card: SoundBlaster X5 (via USB 3.0)
mic: MadDog GM302
os: Ubuntu 22.04

I've tried solution from: [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123065/soundblaster-g6-microphone-input-doesnt-work)

It works ... semi works. Mic in apps like skype working "fine", but audacity and the others getting a very silent signal. After amplify effect I hear my cooling system and other noise.

Any idease, whats wrong?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try PulseaudioVolumeControl `pavucontrol`.